# Как работать с cursorLoader'ом?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Доброго времени суток, [RU.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)!

Есть приложение, которое работает с БД. Для записи, чтения и обновления используется `ContentProvider` + `ArrayList<>` + `ArrayAdapter` + `Cursor`. Но недавно узнал, что существует `cursorLoader`, который существенно облегчит работу. 
Почитал о нем на [startAndroid](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html), но по сути его работы ничего не понял. Назначение ясно, а как он все таки работает ? И как мне его заточить на работу с двумя таблицами ?

Google документация не помогла также.

Пример моего кода по обновлению данных в `spinner'е`:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqldb = new DBClass(getActivity()).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor spinUpdCurcor = sqldb.query(DBClass.TOW_PRICE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,
            DBClass.TOW_COL_TOW);
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    while (spinUpdCurcor.moveToNext()) {
        labels.add(spinUpdCurcor.getString(spinUpdCurcor.getColumnIndex(DBClass.TOW_COL_TOW)));
    }
    if (labels.size() > 0) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "asd " + labels.size());
        /** Создание адаптера для spinner */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterUPD = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.double_fields_tow_spin, R.id.towField, labels);
        towSpin.setAdapter(adapterUPD);
        adapterUPD.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else { ... }
    spinUpdCurcor.close();
    sqldb.close();
/** конец кода обновления */
    }
```

Comment: Вы пишете что используете ContentProvider, но в коде нет признаков его использования. Суть работы cursorLoader в том, что он подписывается на обновления базы данных, и обновляет cursorAdapter в этот момент.

Comment: @katso, провайдер использую для вставки в бд. Код выше лишь пример метода в целом.